# How to use IntelliJ Language Injection within custom tag in a JSP

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea

My company uses custom tags in our JSPs to wrap JavaScript.  I cannot get IntelliJ to treat the content of these tags as JavaScript.  Here is a simple example of what our tag looks like.

```
<ui:script>
  //Include javascript here...
  alert('Any code in here is treated as JavaScript');
</ui:script>
```

Any suggestions?  I've tried using Language Injections, but I cannot find the right settings.

I just noticed that the problem is more linked to using JSP-specific language within the `<ui:script>` tag.  A nastier example (notice the ${selectedReportID} tag that's breaking everything):

```
<ui:script>
    new Kamino.DependencyLoader({
        source: [
            '/static/js/modules/folders/Report.js'
        ],

        onSuccess: function () {
            new Kamino.Report({
                id: '${selectedReportID}',
                element: 'content-reporting-report-list'
            });
        }
    }).load();
</ui:script>
```

Comment: Alt+Enter, `Inject Language`, `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is what worked for me in IntelliJ IDEA 12.

Here is the JSP snippet with custom tag (`aui:script`) that renders some javascript code:

[image: before]

As you can see, it is plain text, i.e. alt+enter gives no suggestions etc.

Here is the **XML Tag Injection** I added in **Language Injection settings**:

[image: setting]

Be sure to choose correct namespace. After this, the same code looks like this (expect some minor delay after opening a file):

[image: after]

It is colored differently and, as you can see, the code between `aui:script` tags is aware of javascript context, suggestions are available etc.

Please try if this works for you, I haven't use this as much as I would like :)

Comment: Igor, thanks! It works for me. Only problem I found is IDEA has some issue with js code formatting - for example if I select block of code and want to indent it with tab, IDEA indent it with one space not with 4 as my CodeStyle settings for JavaScript are set.

Comment: Yes, indeed, it works! For IntelliJ IDEA 11 too. Thank you, Igor. Though there is still no corresponding intention action.

Comment: NB: To do that you need the IntellijLang plugin enabled. It is bundled and enabled by default, but if like me you have configured your intellij idea with just the plugins you need, you may have disabled it.

Comment: This injected colors for me. But indents are not applied. How can I solve it?